# Testing with Realm and XCTest -- Permission Denied?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, realm

Whenever I try to read or write from the Realm within an XCTest, I'm getting this permission denied error: `"RLMException", "open() failed: Permission denied"`.

Even after making sure that the default Realm is set to a different path (`RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath("TestRealm")`) before any test is run, the problem still persists.

I'd like to avoid losing simplicity by passing through a Realm with every model function to accommodate testing them. The [docs](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.88.0/#testing) state it's possible, but I can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath(_:)` is expecting an absolute path to the Realm file, so "TestRealm" is not a suitable path. Changing that to a path that the process has write access to should fix your issue.

Comment: That did it! Path used, for reference: `let resourcePath = NSBundle(forClass: self).resourceURL!.path; let testRealmPath = resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.realm"); RLMRealm.setDefaultRealmPath(testRealmPath)`